# Modify data in Powershell recursive function

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm trying to create a powershell menu from some data inputs and I want an option to modify a parameter. I know that I'm doing wrong, but I don't find the correct way to do it. This is an example:

```
function callData($data){

    write-host "folder selected: " $data
    write-host "write NEWFOLDER to change folder"

    $accion = Read-host "option"

    switch ($accion)
    {
        'NEWFOLDER' {
            $data = changeData
            calldata $data
        }

        Default {}
    }
}


function changeData(){
    $newdata = read-host "New Folder"
    return $newdata
}

$data = read-host "Folder"

while($true){
    callData $data
}
```

Yes, I know, it's not beautiful and it doen't work correctly. With this code, it shows the new value the first time but in next loop it shows again the orignal value. My objective is to modify the original $data with the new value. I hope you understand me...

Comment: What does "modify" entail here? You want to rename the folder? Create a new subfolder?

Comment: I want to use $data as parameter in other functions, like a destination folder...

Comment: Then call the other function instead of calling `calldata` recursively :) If you want to repeat the menu displayed, use a loop

Comment: If you are wondering why the `$data` variable that is before the `while` loop is not getting updated then you must read [`about_Scopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I forced the desired scope to the variable and now it's working. Probably it's not the cleanest solution, but it works.

Comment: @T.S. it is definitely recommend to use the `$script:` scope over the `$global:` scope in almost all cases.

Comment: yes, I used $script: scope. Thanks!